# Why is the python MPI allreduce returning an input list?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I have the following example problem using the allreduce function from mpi4py to find the minimum of each element in the lists across multiple processes. However, the resulting list is not correct. The output of allreduce is always one of the input lists. How can this be corrected?

Output

```
Rank 0: [2, 3, 6, 6, 10, 0, 9, 2, 4, 1]
Allreduce: [0, 0, 4, 4, 1, 0, 10, 10, 1, 5]
Rank 1: [4, 7, 8, 1, 3, 2, 1, 8, 2, 10]
Rank 2: [6, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3, 7, 6, 10, 4]
Rank 3: [7, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 6, 5, 9, 10]
Rank 4: [0, 0, 4, 4, 1, 0, 10, 10, 1, 5]
Rank 5: [1, 9, 3, 5, 9, 4, 9, 5, 4, 5]
Rank 6: [1, 4, 6, 10, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3]
Rank 7: [8, 8, 8, 2, 7, 7, 9, 2, 1, 2]
Rank 8: [7, 2, 4, 10, 7, 7, 5, 2, 9, 1]
Rank 9: [3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 10, 7, 4, 2, 5]
```

Code

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import random
    
#MPI Parallelization
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD # gets communication pool 
rank = comm.Get_rank()  # gets rank of current process 
num_ranks = comm.Get_size() # total number of processes
 
r = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(0,10)]
    
print("Rank " + str(rank) + ": " + str(r))
  
comm.Barrier()
rr = comm.allreduce(r, op=MPI.MIN)
   
if rank == 0:
    print("Allreduce: " + str(rr))
```

Comment: Your code and your output do not belong together: your code has as print statement with `Allreduce` and the output has `Reduce`. Could you give the output that is actually from the code? Btw, that barrier has no function. Barriers are hardly ever needed.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, but it was from the same code. I only edited the print statement in the code before posting here for clarity, but forgot to update it. It's been corrected.

Comment: Very strange. However, you would do best to follow the advice to use numpy. It does not look as nice and "pythonic" but it can be much faster, for larger datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, `mpi4py` works best with `numpy`.

Here is an allreduce example:
(do note with `numpy` you should use `Allreduce(...)` instead of `allreduce(...)`

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import random
import numpy as np
    
#MPI Parallelization
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD # gets communication pool 
rank = comm.Get_rank()  # gets rank of current process 
num_ranks = comm.Get_size() # total number of processes
 
r = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10)
rr = np.empty(10, dtype=int)
    
print("Rank " + str(rank) + ": " + str(r))
  
comm.Barrier()
comm.Allreduce([r, MPI.INT], [rr, MPI.INT], op=MPI.MIN)
   
if rank == 0:
    print("Allreduce: " + str(rr))
```

In your case, I would suspect the outcome of `MPI.MIN` applied to a python list is not a list with the minimum elements, and hence you would get the full buffer of a given rank.

Comment: Thank you! I think you are right. When I convert them to numpy arrays, it works as expected.